# Postgresql: Is there any way to read from a PGDATA/base directory and import the data to a new database?

Tags: database, postgresql, recovery

My database crashed, but I backed up PGDATA/base earlier, so I lost the 
database structure and only have the base directory(maybe part of it),
so I decide to build a new database same as the old one since I lost
the structure file, but I don't know whether the data in the base
directory can be imported to the new database's table, is there any way 
can do that?

Last check I have `/etc/postgresql/10/main` folder and 
`/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/` folder of the crashed database, and data folder like I said, I only have the `base`

Working on Ubuntu16.04 Postgresql-10

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `$PGDATA/base`, you are missing

1. The commit log that says which transaction was committed and which aborted, so you don't know what rows are visible.
2. The control file `global/pg_control` that tells you the state of the database and the last checkpoint and other important information.
3. The transaction log.
4. The global tablespace that contains the users and tablespaces.

In short, your database is toast. Perhaps a specialist can rescue some of the data.

Comment: Sad. That is to say, I can't import the data which the `base` folder holds directly into new database right? Because I can't distinguish rows

Comment: You are missing relevant parts of the database's brain.